# SqlPlus - define variable substring

Tags: sqlplus

I'm new in sqlplus, and I'm having difficulties with the basic usage of variables :)

I have the following:

`define PROJECT_VERSION='1.1-SNAPSHOT'`

I'd like to create an other variable, which contains the same info without the `-SNAPSHOT` part (so its value is `1.1`). Of course I don't want to type `define PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP='1.1'`, instead of it something like `define PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP=replace(&PROJECT_VERSION,'-SNAPSHOT','')` were more appropriate.

How can I do it?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggested *almost* works; you need to enclose your base variable in single quotes though:

```
define PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP=replace('&PROJECT_VERSION','-SNAPSHOT',null)

select &PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP from dual;

old:select &PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP from dual
new:select replace('1.1-SNAPSHOT','-SNAPSHOT',null) from dual

REP
---
1.1
```

I've left `verify` on so you can see that the `replace()` operation will be repeated every time that substitution variable is referenced later, which isn't necessarily a big deal, but something to be aware of.

You could also use [the `column ... new_value` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm) to define the variable:

```
undefine PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP
column TMP_VERSION new_value PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP
select replace('&PROJECT_VERSION','-SNAPSHOT',null) as TMP_VERSION from dual;

old:select replace('&PROJECT_VERSION','-SNAPSHOT',null) as TMP_VERSION from dual
new:select replace('1.1-SNAPSHOT','-SNAPSHOT',null) as TMP_VERSION from dual

TMP
---
1.1

select &PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP from dual;

old:select &PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP from dual
new:select 1.1 from dual

       1.1
----------
       1.1
```

Now you can see that references use the value directly, without repeating the `replace()` - it only happens once in that column-setting query. You can `set termout off` and then `on` around the query that sets the variable to hide it, in addition to `set verify off`.

Another approach is to define the variables the other way around:

```
undefine PROJECT_VERSION
undefine PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP
define PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP=1.1
define PROJECT_VERSION='&PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP.-SNAPHOT'

select '&PROJECT_VERSION', &PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP from dual;

old:select '&PROJECT_VERSION', &PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP from dual
new:select '1.1-SNAPHOT', 1.1 from dual

'1.1-SNAPHO        1.1
----------- ----------
1.1-SNAPHOT        1.1
```

but that assumes the `snapshot` part if always required, and from the way you asked the question I suspect that can change.

Yet another approach is to use bind variables throughout instead of substitution variables:

```
var PROJECT_VERSION varchar2(20);
var PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP varchar2(20);
exec :PROJECT_VERSION := '1.1-SNAPSHOT';
exec :PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP := replace(:PROJECT_VERSION,'-SNAPSHOT',null);

select :PROJECT_VERSION, :PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP from dual;

:PROJECT_VERSION                 :PROJECT_VERSION_WOSNAP
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
1.1-SNAPSHOT                     1.1
```

but again that might not work for whatever you are doing later.